# Как преобразовать аудиофайл в массив байтов?

Tags: java, android, аудио

Есть код где я создаю интент и получаю Uri аудио файла,
мне необходимо по Uri преобразовать файл в массив байтов для дальнейшего копирования в другую директорию и загрузки в firebase

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button play;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        play = findViewById(R.id.button_play);
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            getrack();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==1 && data !=null && data.getData() !=null){
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            Log.i("MYLOOOOG", "URI"+ data.getData());

            
            }
        }
    }

    private void getrack(){
        Intent intentchooser = new Intent();
        intentchooser.setType("audio/*");
        intentchooser.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intentchooser, 1);
    }
}
```